# Navigating and Determine full path in FInder save-as dialog Mac OS X

Tags: macos, directory, finder

How do you navigate the directory structure in a save as dialog on Mac OS X (Finder). Can Apple really have botched the simple funcitonality?

Comment: You click the downward-facing arrow and then smack your head.

Answer (score 1):

There's a down-arrow to the right of the text field. Click it to see the full navigation interface. The default interface is simplified. This question is better asked on superuser.

Comment: a related question: can you access the path *as text* so you can copy it and paste into a terminal? The ephemeral cmd-shift-G doesn't work - it gives you a text path, but not the one currently selected in the save-as dialog ):

Comment: Most items can be dragged to the terminal. When you do that, it'll paste the full path.

Comment: You can also copy in the finder GUI to put a things path on the clipboard (and paste into the terminal), but that doesn't seem to work with save-as dialogs ): A pity - I generally prefer copy-paste to dragging.